# Are there any special key symbols/words that cannot be used in the Oracle Queue (or just save as a char value in the Oracle)?

Tags: oracle, message-queue

I'm a newbie to use Oracle Queue, I wanna know whether there are some symbols/words that cannot be directly used in the Oracle Queue(or just save as a char value in the Oracle)?

If I insist using them, how to convert them as valid ones?

I was told that English dot (.) cannot be used?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use double quotes to quote oracle keywords.

For example you can create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE timeframe (
    "DATE" DATE,
    "FROM" DATE,
    "TO"   DATE
);
```

Be aware that quoted names are case sensitive!

Comment: Are there any special symbols like English dot?